# cleanup_module linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a wait queue defined in a kernel module I am working on:

```
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(WaitQ);
```

in the `init_module()` routine I create a new kernel thread which prints to the console every few seconds.

In my `cleanup_module` I set a variable which tells the thread to terminate and then have `sleep_on(&WaitQ)` as the last line in `cleanup_module`.  Then in the thread routine `wake_up(&WaitQ)` is called when the variable set in `cleanup_module` is true, and then `complete_and_exit` to terminate the thread.

My question is.  when sleep_on(&WaitQ) is called what is addded to the WaitQ. Is it the module as a whole or is it the thread started in the init_module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither - what is added to the queue is the thread (task) of the "rmmod" processor that caused  the module removal.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to all this so I don't fully understand. So in my case when sleep_on is called the routine I defined is still operating so what is actually sleeping in this case?

Comment: The task of the "rmmod" utility that called the system call that caused cleanup_module to get called.

Comment: ok so sleep_on is called to put the task to sleep in order to wait on the routine I started to finish what it's doing.  The routine calls wake_up(&WaitQ) to wake up the task to tell it that it has finshed what its doing and then it can proceed on to complete_and_exit terminating the thread.  After this the module is removed. Does this sound correct?

Comment: I don't know if it is correct or not (need to see actual code, think about race conditions, SMP support etc) but it sounds like what I understand is happening.